# What is dual representation in plain English?

Tags: logic, representation-theory, duality-theorems

Can someone please explain what is Dual representation in plain English. I read its definition on wikipedia and at many other places but could not develop an intution for it. Please explain in plain english without lots of mathematical definitions.

How is following a Dual Representation :
[image]

Comment: First, do you know what a representation is?  And do you know what a dual space is.

Comment: I don't know about dual space. On wikipedia its very mathematically oriented definition. I am not from a Mathematical background. Could you please explain in simple language that i can understand. @Betty Mock

Comment: If you do not knwo what the dual space is, the very best thing you can do is to pick a linear álgebra textbook and read about it. When you get somewhat acquianted with it, then you can probably understand what the dual representation is.

Comment: @Amber Do you know what a vector space is?  Without this much there is no explaining anything.  If you are familiar with vector spaces I could offer you some steps in the right direction.  Why do you need to know what a dual representation is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of looking at this. The first is in coordinates, where you regard the representation as mapping your group to a group of matrices with coordinates in your favorite field. You can produce a new representation from this by taking each matrix in the original representation and inverting, then transposing, it.

The second is abstractly. A linear representation of a group is a group action on a vector space. The dual space is the set of linear functionals on the vector space. The only obvious way to define a representation on the dual space is by taking a given functional and precomposing it with the inverted representation on the vector space.

It may be worth asking why you invert the representation before precomposing with a functional (alternatively, why you invert the matrix before transposing it). There's a technical reason to do this: so that the dual representation actually turns into a group homomorphism. If $\rho:G\to GL(V)$, $g,h\in G$, $v\in V$, and $f\in V^*$, then
$$\rho^*(gh)(f)(v) = f(\rho(gh)v) = f(\rho(h)\rho(g)v) = \rho^*(h)f(\rho(g)v)=\rho^*(h)\rho^*(g)f(v)$$
doesn't actually work.

Comment: Can you give me some example of a Dual representation.

Comment: @Amber Take your favorite representation. Invert each matrix and then take their transposes. There's the dual representation.

Comment: I have added an equation in my question. Please explain how does that represent a Dual representation. You can assume the value of Variables as you like.

Comment: @Amber I can't say anything more than vague generalities about that equation without more context.

Comment: That would suffice. I just need a hint that how this equation may be representing a dual representation. Take any assumption you want.

Comment: @Amber Then please provide more context, especially what $\phi$, $\Phi$, and $K$ are.